# get a unique generated id for users

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

I need a unique key for every user in my database so I am using the microtime details using timestamp, and then adding to that string an id generated by uniqid so I get a unique key. The problem I have is that the key has too many characters. What if I want to generate a small id (for example, facebook's user ids). Please also tell me if 8 characters key will be good enough to uniquely identify my users.

If not, can you suggest another way to generate a unique identifier?

Can you tell me if there are there any problems with the method I described?

I know this may appear to be a duplicate but I have specific needs, hence this question.

Comment: Why can't you use an auto-incrementing integer?

Comment: k..but should i do it using the database feature or a user class with static counter sort of variable and if with the database way then wouldnt it have to start from 1 i only want 6-8 characters id

Answer (score 2):

Make a field in your database called `user_id` and set it to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  SQL will automatically assign a unique number to each user, and you can call it using `SELECT` queries.

Comment: how will i set it to be between 6-8 characters

Comment: @tushar: Depending on the RDBMS you're using, you can either set it to start at 100000, or insert a record (with auto-increment off) with a value of 100000 to start counting from there.

Comment: @tushar: Keep in mind that a limit of 6-8 characters on a numeric field limits your possible number of records to 99,899,999.  But then, if you plan on breaking the hundred million mark, you have other scalability concerns :)

Answer (score 0):

Tushar,

This question is incredibly hard to read without punctuation.

What RDBMS are you using? Bear in mind that some types have a maximum length of characters.

There are simplier ways to generate a Unique ID for a Primary Key. Autoincrement for MySQL is a popular technique. Sequences for Oracle are another.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). PHP can't generate these natively (you will need to download a class for this), or your SQL server can handle this; for example, MySQL has [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) and MSSQL has [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx).

Also, if you are going to be using this ID in your frontend (like how FB uses it to view profiles), you will probably **not** want to use incrementing ID's. If you do, clever users will be able to simply change the ID in the URL to access any user that they want to.

Comment: exactly so how do i get the security feature and also make it within the character length

Comment: @tushar, just making something harder to guess isn't a security feature. You're application has to provide protection against just guessing another user's ID and magically becoming them.

Comment: yes!!but wont the session variables be enough to care of that

Comment: jasonbar is right, you will still need to implement the proper security controls. My point is that using sequential ID's provides for a much easier attack or exploit. For instance, if I wanted to try to crack a password on your site using a dictionary, it would be trivial to set it up to start at 1 and go to 1000 (to try on the first 1000 users). On the other hand, if you used UUID's, it'd be *much* harder to discover users which you could attempt to brute force attack.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use incremented keys,

```
// define this someplace, and with something other than abc...
define('SOME_SALT', 'abcdefghijkl');
$id = substr(sha1($username . SOME_SALT), 0, 8);
```

Where `$username` is the account username (or some other piece of data unique to the account).

Comment: and is the uniqueness in this code strong enough coz i am using substring after encrypting doesnt that increase the chance of collision

Comment: Yes, reducing the length of the string increases the chances of collision. You aren't going to get "totally unique" and "very short" together unless you use incrementing ids.

Comment: ok...so does fb manage to create a balance between the length,security and uniqueness as id is available to us and its not encrypted so how does it do that..?

Comment: @tushar, for users that have not defined a "pretty" profile url, facebook uses integer IDs. They appear to be sequential (look up a profile by id, add one and you get another profile, add another, etc...)